# PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR: argument of AND must be type boolean, not type integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've developed a basic application in Rails using MySQL. I'm converting over to a PostgreSQL db. I got the database setup and most of my queries work except for one that has a `many to many` relationship.

My models look like this:

```
User has_and_belongs_to_many :locations

Location has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

However, I'm getting the following error when I execute this line of code:

```
location = current_user.locations.find_by(cookies[:current_location])
```

Produces this error:

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of AND must be type boolean, not type integer
LINE 1: ...n_id" WHERE "locations_users"."user_id" = $1 AND (1) LIMIT $...
                                                         ^
: SELECT  "locations".* FROM "locations" INNER JOIN "locations_users" ON "locations"."id" = "locations_users"."location_id" WHERE "locations_users"."user_id" = $1 AND (1) LIMIT $2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `find_by` expects one or more key-value pairs. For instace, `find_by(current_location: cookies[:current_location])`.

Comment: That worked. Thanks

Comment: Added as an answer in case you care to accept/upvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find_by` expects one or more key-value pairs. For instance:

```
location = current_user.locations.find_by(current_location: cookies[:current_location])
```